# Keep absolutely positioned element inside of Bootstrap modal body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get an absolutely positioned element to stay within the bounds of a bootstrap modals modal-body element? In my example below, it is out of the containing modal-body div bounds:

```css
.node {
   width: 300px;
   min-height: 180px;
   position:absolute;
   margin:5px;
   border:3px solid black;
   background-color: blue;
}
.modal-body {
   position: relative;
   border: 2px solid green;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="show-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch modal
</button>

 <div id="myModal"  class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        MODAL BODY
  <div id="1" class="node">ABSOLUTELY</div>


 </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --
```

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to `.modal-body` and position your node by at least one of sides (otherwise it will behave like posioned relatively).

Comment: `min-height: 180px`.  What determines the height of `.node`?  Is it an image, text, both?

Comment: @Przemysław Melnarowicz - bootstrap's modal-body already has position: relative, but I added to the question for clarity - same results.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle - it's just text

Comment: @user210757 That's going to be a problem.  The fact that it's `position:absolute` takes it out of flow.  There will be no way with CSS alone to determine what the height should be because the flow of the surrounding elements is not affected by the element itself.  What's the reason for using `position:absolute` here?  Could you instead substitute `position:relative` which doesn't take the element out of flow?

Comment: @JosephMarikle - There are many of the elements, and I am dynamically positioning them with jquery.  I couldn't get this to work with any other positioning

Comment: @user210757 Yeah.  Unless you can reasonably predict the aspect ratio, this will not possible with CSS.  Of course you can also tie into bootstrap's modal events to tell when the modal is open and calculate the height of the absolutely positioned elements.  From there you can set the height explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the parent element has a `position` of `relative`, `fixed` or `absolute`. Basically, anything but the default `position: static`.

From there you can position it using things like `left: 20px` or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: it does - bootstrap's modal-body has position: relative, but I'll add that to question for clarity

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow entirely. You would need to either change it from `position: absolute` to `relative` or you would need to have a hidden sibling element that has the same height as your `position: absolute` div to "trick" the containing element to be as tall as you need it to be.